# Tips in how to create a site like Apple in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design

I want to create a website with the same style as the Apple website.

Where should I start?

For the ones who don't know, this is the style I'm looking for: http://www.instantshift.com/2010/01/30/40-apple-inspired-website-designs-for-design-inspiration/

Being a photoshop beginner, I don't know where to start and I can't find any tutorial.

Thanks

Comment: This is awfully broad. I would recommend splitting the task into sub-tasks (layout; building and styling a menu; buttons; font selection; colour palette...) and ask specific questions about each where necessary

Comment: @Pekka, thanks for the answer but I don't have enough knowledge so I can know where to start asking that. I'd like some tips if possible. thanks

Comment: follow tutorials and you"ll get knowledge easily..by doing only you come to know how easy and hard things can be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pekkas comment is where you need to focus on. Consider his recommendation to split the project into tasks. Pekka allready told you where to start:

- layout.

after that you go on with the next logical task. -your choice- color palette, menu (&sitemap), buttons etc. You can come up with this tasks automatically if you actually start thinking about layout and your site as a project.

What is the content of the site? Who is my typical user? Students? Artists? Hairdressers? Ask yourself questions that help you define what design elements are necessary and how they should be placed and accessed. Then comes the graphical part where you get to choose a general style and look, how to apply it and compare how others did it on their projects.

The posted link to the tutorial on the other hand offers no chance to really learn about the actual design process where YOU decide.

The answer provided by Jack feels wrong. A bit like the fastfood version of an answer to your question. Following tutorials mechanically lets very little room for progress. You get more tech savvy but that's about it.

Jacks answer is valid but takes you down a wrong path, IMO. I hope this comes not of as a rant.

Comment: Agreed, photoshop is a good starting point for layout, as for actually building the site/pages it is the wrong tool. For a site as rich as apples you need a very sound understanding of HTML, CSS and Javascript. Tutorials are OK but you need to get a good grounding of the basics. An example is that I always know when out "Lead Designer" has been doing Javascript as the code is littered with words like "demo" & "sample" indicating he has no understanding of the underlying principles.

Comment: What I wanted to empathize is not so much the role of photoshop as ONE type of tool among others necessary for website building. But more importantly the need to actually _develop_ a project such as the creation of a site. I guess what I was arguing against was the conclusion someone _could_ make be seeing the question and the tutorial link in combination: That this is enough to create a website. It IS enough to replicate visuals but not for understanding the underlying reasons. The conclusions of the former being what you actually keep. Styles get outdated eventually & become less meaningful.

Comment: leugim, your answer would be perfect if you could advice some books or anything in order for me to learn.  It's very tough to enter the "design world" without any prior knowledge. Thanks

Comment: @donald Sorry to get back to you this late but since you asked for books or similar to learn from... Wucius Wong has a few books that cover many aspects of design (general principles) this books are very appropriate in covering the basics of color, form etc in design. Additionally: What I found most objectable was the apparent (mis?)conception that you could tackle a webdesign by following a tutorial on a specific graphic style rather than making a genuine design-exersice out of it.  Generally I do this: 1.Identify the need. 2.Identify the type of users. 3.Research (a lot) 4.design.

Comment: @donald 4.Design is a whole chapter by itself. This is why your question was deemed too broad. 4.1 could be general layout and functionality. 4.2 etc... research a bit by yourself. You will learn a lot. And by the 5th or so try you'll get passable results :). Be assured that the graphical designing parts come nearly at the last stages of the design and that is the only place where you will be able to deliver the best results... Because by then you are soaked with knowledge on the topic. But ... I could also be wrong :)

Answer (score 2):

here you go

detailed tutorial just for you

http://trendytuts.com/web-layout-tutorials/create-a-web-layout-in-photoshop-using-the-apple-style.html